Not able to upload a file on button click in react with mui
The link has a Live example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ashok-reddy?file=myform.tsx,package.json,file.tsx
When user click on select file button to up load the file ,button was not opening to upload the file
2.When user drag and drop the file was able to uploading the file
3.Therefore issue was here button was not opening to upload the file

Current behavior:
When user click on select file button to up load the file ,button was not opening to upload the file
below screenshot shows when user click on select file button*


When user drag and drop the file was able to uploading the file 
below screenshot shows when user drag and drop the file was able to uploading the file.


Expected behavior:
When user click on select file button to up load the file ,it should able to open to upload the file successfully .


const mission = async (formdata: any) => {
    const encontersHttpService = new EncontersHttpService();
    return await encontersHttpService.post<any, unknown>(URL, formdata, {}, true).then(response => response).catch(error => console.log(error.message))
}

export const OnSubmit = () => {
    return useMutation<any, Error, any>({
        mutationKey: [ISSION],
        mutationFn: (formdata: any) => mission(formdata)
    })
}
 const { mutateAsync, isPending} = OnSubmit();
 mutateAsync(formData, {
                    onSuccess: (data) => {
                        if (!isPending) {
                            
                        }
                    },
                    onError: (error) => {
                        console.log(error.message)

                    },
                })



When user click on select file button to up load the file ,it should able to open to upload the file successfully .


I am not sure why you are passing 3 refs to <TextField /> component at your fileupload.tsx file as when clicking on Select File button you run fileInputRef.current?.click() script.
So you can change <TextField /> component's ref to receive only fileInputRef instead.
<TextField
  type="file"
  onChange={handleFileChange}
  style={{ display: 'none' }}
  inputRef={fileInputRef} // Changed this line
/>

If you want to open file dialog when clicking on <Paper /> component as well add onClick event.
<Paper
  elevation={isDragging ? 6 : 1}
  sx={{ ...styles }}
  onDragOver={handleDragOver}
  onDragEnter={handleDragEnter}
  onDragLeave={handleDragLeave}
  onDrop={handleDrop}
  onClick={() => fileInputRef.current?.click()} // added this line
>
  {children}
</Paper>

If you implement opening the dialog when clicking on <Paper /> make sure you have a div wrapper around your <Box /> component which will preserve not opening the dialog when clicking on already selected file area.
{selectedFile && (
  <div onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}>
    <Box>{children}</Box>
  </div>
)}


Can you help me where exactly need to place the following code in box above live example code ? because i was not able to achieve it? -{selectedFile && (
 e.stopPropagation()}>
    {children}

)}
I did the change, can you see it?

NO , i didn't  .I couldn't see your changes in live example ? i don't how it was removed ? can you please re update it once again?

check with this URL - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ashok-reddy-sgvzzt?file=fileupload.tsx

@alexandr.mirzoyan..Thank you .. I'm not getting an idea how to upload multiples files ? can you please suggest me how to implement from the live example ? just an idea to start of it/

? do you have any idea about my above ask?

Make your selectedFile state as an array of files instead of 1 single file. Make corresponding setSelectedFile() function call changes so it will handle array data structure. And after that loop through the list of the files during rendering and show needed details.

Please if the above answer helped you for solving button click issue, vote for the answer as I am trying to gain reputation :) And your voice matters!
